# Table Row not lining up

Tags: html, html-table

I created a table to display a shopping cart. My first two rows line up perfectly, but the last row doesn't. I tried recreating it and still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

To make it more readable, I took out the first two rows and just left the last row that is causing the problems.:

**CSS**

```
     .gallery-list
     {   
     }
     .gallery-list .container
    { 
        clear:both;
        width:100%;
        padding-top:10px; 
        padding-bottom:10px; 
    } 
    .gallery-list .container .imgContainer
    {
        width:25%;
        float:left;
        padding-top:5px;
    }
    .gallery-list .container  .imgContainer img
    {
        width:98%; 
    }
    .gallery-list .container .descContainer
    {
        width:74%;
        float:left;
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    .gallery-grid
    {

    }
    .gallery-grid .container
    {  
        width:33%;
        padding-top:10px; 
        padding-bottom:10px; 
        float:left;
    } 
    .gallery-grid .container .imgContainer
    {

    }
    .gallery-grid .container .imgContainer img
    {
        width:98%; 
    }
    .gallery-grid .container .descContainer
    {
        display: none;
    }

    ul.pager
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
    .pager li {display: inline; }
    .pager li a {padding:5px; border:solid 1px #ccc;margin:2px;}
    .current
    {
        color:black;

    }
    .current:hover
    {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    #pager
    {
        clear:both;
    }
```

**html**

```
     <tr>
            <td>
            <div class="gallery-list"> 



        <div class="container">
            <div class="imgContainer">

                <img  src=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="descContainer">
                <div class="name">
                    <h2 style="color:#000;text-transform:uppercase;margin:0;">Friday Night and Saturday Activities (Single)</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                                    </div>
                <div class="shortcode">
                     <object class="simpleecommcartAddToCartButton">




     <form id='cartButtonForm_1' class="SimpleEcommCartCartButton" method="post" action="http://beauwaldrop.com/ahs83/store/cart/" >
     <input type='hidden' name='task' id="task_1" value='addToCart' />
     <input type='hidden' name='simpleecommcartItemId' value='1' />

     <input type='hidden' name='hascartwidget' class="hascartwidget" value='no' />




      <span style="color:#666;font-size:1.1em;"><em></em></span>

      <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:1.01em;">Price: $89.00</span>


           <input type="hidden" name="item_quantity" class="SimpleEcommCartItemQuantityInput" value="1">       




                 <br><input type='submit' value='Add To Cart' name='addToCart_1' id='addToCart_1' />





          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="check_inventory_on_add_to_cart" />
      <div id="stock_message_box_1" class="SimpleEcommCartUnavailable" style="display: none;">
        <h2>We're Sorry</h2>
        <p id="stock_message_1"></p>
        <input type="button" name="close" value="Ok" id="close" class="modalClose" />
      </div>

     </form>



     </object>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
            </td>
            <td>
      <div class="container">
      <div class="imgContainer">             
      <img  src=""/>
      </div>
      <div class="descContainer">
      <div class="name">
      <h2 style="color:#000;text-transform:uppercase;margin:0;">Friday Night and Saturday Activities (Couple)</h2>
      </div>            
     <div class="desc">
                                    </div>
                <div class="shortcode">
                     <object class="simpleecommcartAddToCartButton">

      <form id='cartButtonForm_2' class="SimpleEcommCartCartButton" method="post" action="http://beauwaldrop.com/ahs83/store/cart/" >
      <input type='hidden' name='task' id="task_2" value='addToCart' />
      <input type='hidden' name='simpleecommcartItemId' value='2' />

      <input type='hidden' name='hascartwidget' class="hascartwidget" value='no' />

      <span style="color:#666;font-size:1.1em;"><em></em></span>

      <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:1.01em;">Price: $129.00</span>

           <input type="hidden" name="item_quantity" class="SimpleEcommCartItemQuantityInput" value="1">                 

                 <br><input type='submit' value='Add To Cart' name='addToCart_2' id='addToCart_2' />       
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="check_inventory_on_add_to_cart" />
      <div id="stock_message_box_2" class="SimpleEcommCartUnavailable" style="display: none;">
        <h2>We're Sorry</h2>
        <p id="stock_message_2"></p>
        <input type="button" name="close" value="Ok" id="close" class="modalClose" />
      </div>

  </form>
</object>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: `Any ideas?`, yes, how about posting your code? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: We will be happy to help you find the problem. Please edit your question to post the relevant HTML markup along with any styles that may effect the table or problem row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the source of the page, you have closed and reopened the `tr` before your last column which is causing the last two columns to be split like that

Having looked at the posted code there is nothing wrong and it works perfectly:

http://jsfiddle.net/9pPXq/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not seeing what your talking about. I see that I closed and reopned the <td> but not the tr. I even copied the cost and pasted into two different text editors and it lines up correctly.

Comment: where's the link to your site gone?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I fixed it. Something stupid as usual. Thanks for your help.